# Java help -> weird code 

Tags: java

Can someone explain to me this code

```
 new Object[]{"PLease","Help"};
```

Ive never seen code like this before,
so It would be helpful if someone explains these to me.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's short hand for a in-line array.

It's the same as doing...

```
Object[] aArray = new Object[2];
aArray[0] = "PLease";
aArray[1] = "Help";
```

Comment: its NOT the same, in your example the reference aArray exists...in the question the array is anonymous.  If you passed aArray into a method in your example, the reference is passed by value so another reference will exist in the method context.  As written, if the anonymous array was passed into a method, only the method scope could access it.

Comment: true, but details are important.  ;)

Answer (score 24):

You are creating  a new Object array, that has 2 Strings in it, "PLease" and "Help".

The construct you are using is called an *anonymous array*, because you are not assigning the array to anything (useful if you want to pass the array to a method).

See http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch02_09.htm

Comment: yay, 16 up voting in less than 10 mins

Comment: @eng.fouad, yeah i did my usual "submit then go back and edit" and when I came back it was +8 (in like 15 seconds).  I was very surprised. hey, Ill take it ;)

Answer (score 3):

This:

> new Object[]{"PLease","Help"} ;

Is equivalent to:

```
Object[] array = new Object[size];
array[0] = "PLease";
array[1] = "Help";
```

I hope this clears it up a bit.

Comment: aha!(Eureka!) ,  
that means    
  String e = new String[]{"is","it"}  
  
is equal to  
  
String e = new String["or","isn't"]

Comment: @Kebyang in the case you're not joking (which I doubt), **no** thats not what it means :)